# How to get `incorrect password` from keytool?

Tags: android, android-studio, keytool

Windows10 user. I am trying to recover my `keystore` password. I am using `keytool.exe` found in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin`.

I want to eventually change the password, but I am unsure of what the password is. I am trying to get an `incorrect password` error by running a command similar to:

```
keytool -keypasswd -keypass "foo" -new "foobar"-keystore "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\stuff\keystores\android.jks"
```

I have also tried:

```
keytool -keypass "foo" -new "foobar"-keystore "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\stuff\keystores\android.jks"
```

My error message for both is

```
Illegal option:  
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\stuff\keystores\android.jks
```

*****Side Note:**

**I do have the password "Remembered" in Android Studios, and am able to generate new keys and updates with it. My end goal is to transfer the keystore over to my mac. If there is another way to find the password or to handle this configuration, I am all ears.**

Comment: I think I found a way with `keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Me\Desktop\stuff\keystores\android.jks`. This prompts a `Enter keystore password:`. I also tested without quotes in my original attempts. Same error.

Comment: `keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Me\Desktop\stuff\keystores\android.jks` failed attempts are telling me `keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`. Going to give it a few more tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a command that issues a `Enter keystore password:` prompt. Command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Me\Desktop\stuff\keystores\android.jks
```

After a few attempts of doing the incorrect password, I received the error code:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

And finally, I was able to guess my correct password, which output:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: myandroidkey
Creation date: 16-Aug-2018
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
...

*******************************************
*******************************************
```